# Technical perspective vs managerial perspective in software failures

Tags: software, management, technology, failure

I am learning about various causes that lead to software failures. So far, two prominent causes of failures seem to be managerial and technical. An example of the resources I have looked at is this [file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Application_of_Real_Options_theory_to_software_engineering_for_strategic_decision_making_in_software_related_capital_investments_%28IA_applicationofrea1094510317%29.pdf). But I am looking for a more specific explanation.

Could you please give me a short, comprehensive explanation about the aspects of managerial and technical perspectives to failures so that I could learn more about this topic?

Comment: In general, the root cause is misunderstanding or not recognizing the problem. Then the effort will go to things that hardly matter and no progress is made. An additional requirement for failure would be the inability to listen and learn, disinterest, plain stupidity and last but not least, that everyone just does what they are asked to do.

Comment: We do not lookup third-party resources here for askers, sorry. I can reword your question to avoid that pitfall (and will fit more to the one answer it already got), but you will have to double-check if I still got your intententions right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For technical root-causes to a failure, you should look at what the actions engineers did or did not take that have an effect on the failure occurring and why those actions were (not) taken.

For managerial root-causes to a failure, you look at the processes that the organization has in place and why those processes did not prevent the failure.

Comment: Thanks. So my question is what are some types of actions engineers may do to cause failure? Similarly, what are some characteristics of processes that if not followed, lead to failure?

Comment: That question is really too broad for SE. Technical root-causes can literally range from a simple oversight to not understanding all implications of a particular change and just about anything you can imagine.